# Parsec start-of-row pattern?

Tags: haskell, mediawiki, parsec

I am trying to parse mediawiki text using Parsec. Some of the constructs in mediawiki markup can only occur at the start of rows (such as the header markup `==header level 2==`). In regexp I would use an anchor (such as `^`) to find the start of a line.

One attempt in GHCi is

```
Prelude Text.Parsec> parse (char '\n' *> string "==" *> many1 letter <* string "==") "" "\n==hej=="
Right "hej"
```

but this is not too good since it will fail on the first line of a file. I feel like this should be a solved problem...

What is the most idiomatic "Start of line" parsing in Parsec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getPosition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:getPosition) and [`sourceColumn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:sourceColumn) in order to find out the column number that the parser is currently looking at. The column number will be `1` if the current position is at the start of a line (such as at the start of input or after a `\n` or `\r` character).

There isn't a built-in combinator for this, but you can easily make it:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Control.Monad (guard)

startOfLine :: Monad m => ParsecT s u m ()
startOfLine = do
    pos <- getPosition
    guard (sourceColumn pos == 1)
```

Now you can write your header parser as:

```
header = startOfLine *> string "==" *> many1 letter <* string "=="
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use `many (char '\n')` instead of just `char '\n'`. In parser combinators there's no sense of *start of the line* because they always run at the start of input. The only thing you can do is to check manually which symbols your input can start from. Using `many (char '\n')` ensures that there only zero or more empty lines before header `== my header ==`.

Comment: `many (char '\n')` still wouldn't verify that the header is appearing at the start of a line though, since `many` can match anywhere by just matching 0 times.